# How can I get an array of all elements within a specific class using javascript and/or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get an array of all elements with the class "sampleclass". For example, withing my document I have three divs:

```
<div class="aclass"></div>
<div class="sampleclass"></div>
<div class="anotheraclass"></div>
<div class="sampleclass"></div>
```

I want to get an array with all elements that are within the "sampleclass" using javascipt and/or jQuery.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Just to clarify - which browsers do you need to support? JQuery should support most, some DOM methods dont work across the board.

Comment: You want all the elements INSIDE the `sampleclass` element? If yes then there is a typo in the question, and most people have answered wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get all the elements inside each element containing the `sampleclass` class:

```
var myArray = $('.sampleclass *');
```

`*` is called the [All selector](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/)

**EDIT**: please note, in this example:

```
<div id="test">
   <table>
      <tr><td>TEST</td></tr>
   </table>
</div>

var myArray = $('#test *');
```

`myArray` contains all the sub-elements of the div: `table`, `tr` and `td`.

If you want all the *top-level* elements inside a given element, you can try:

```
var myArray = $('#test > *');
```

This combines the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) with the aforementioned [all selector](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$( '.sampleclass' );
```

You can then iterate through the array with `each`.

Comment: What Jacob said. Alternately, without jQuery, `document.getElementsByClassName('sampleclass');`

Answer (score 1):

......

```
$('.sampleclass').........
```

Further you can iterate over it using `each` like this:

```
$('.sampleclass').each(function(){
  // more code........
})
```

And finally, you can get each individual item like this too:

```
$('.sampleclass')[0]; // first
$('.sampleclass')[1]; // second
// and so on........
```

Comment: -1 for just copy-paste the other 2 answers. Also, that last bit of code is terrible for performance -- CACHE the result.

Comment: @Coronatus: it is ridiculouse that you said copy-paste. My ansewr was posted before yours. This is very basic thing for me, so i don't need to copy-paste. Go to my blog to know my jquery skills just by going through my profile or even have a lookt at my SO answers in jquery tag. Consider your vote again....Thanks

Comment: moderator should take notice of this please.

Comment: @Coronatus: What do you mean please, any consideration to what you did?

Comment: Heehee: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44413/all-my-answers-being-downvoted-by-one-angry-user

Comment: @Coronatus:You said 'lol' which is not a better explanation to my correct answer being down voted. Still waiting for your explanation.

Comment: @Coronatus: Remember, doing bad results in bad. Check the comments of developers at meta.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding Jacob Relkin' answer:

```
$('.sampleClass').each(function()
{
   // do something with it...
   $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
});
```